# Because/ Since symbol in latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm having a hard time finding the because or since symbol in latex. alternatively is there a way to just flip `\therefore` in latex?

Comment: This site gives examples of the `because` symbol [because symbol](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15309)

Comment: You just need to load the `amssymb` package.

Comment: @IanThompson  No I've checked

Comment: @EconJohn --- It works for me.